# "A lot simpler" or "a lot more simple"?

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

> Using 8va and 16va in music notation makes music sheets tidier and reading them becomes a lot (simpler/more simple).

Which sounds better and is more common?

Comment: Why do you want to know which one sounds better and is more common? They both sound fine and mean the same thing and are both used quite frequently. As long as it *be* good English, what does it matter?

Comment: @Nick I'm supposed to choose one or the other, which makes me think keeping the more common one is in a way much better than sticking to the less common one out of the two.

Comment: To be honest, Alex, they're both so common that I do not know which is more common. I know *more common* is more common than *commoner*, but *simpler* and *more simple* are both said and written so often that I could not begin to tell you which one is more common. I would personally say "a lot **simpler**", but I may be in the minority; I just don't know.

Comment: I also know that I say **stupider** and **stupidest** very often, but that is apparently not so common as **more stupid** and **most stupid** because I've had native speakers correct me only for me to correct them back! I tell them it can be both and, if they disagree, I show them. I hear **stupider** and **stupidest** about one out of every five times a comparative and superlative are used for the adjective "stupid". As for "simple", I think they are probably equal--for every one **more simple**, I'll hear a **simpler** the next time.

Comment: I think there might be a preference for "simpler" just because it parallels the "tidier" from earlier in the sentence.  So while either choice is grammatical, the choice of "simpler" sounds a little nicer to the ear in this particular sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you, Alex! As for your question: they are both common and they both sound fine.  You can say, "It's a lot **simpler**," or, "It's a lot **more simple**." I don't have one of those N Grams to show you which one is *more common* (or *commoner*).  I am just going to tell you that either one can be used and is *correct* English.